# Why doesn't Sphinx translate :kbd: roles to HTML's <kbd> tags?

Tags: html, css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I want to mark keyboard keys and inputs as key "icons". Sphinx provides a `:kbd:` role to markup single characters or words, but the resulting HTML contains `<code class="kbd ......">` tags.

So why doesn't Sphinx translate :kbd: roles to HTML's  tags?

(I'm using the read-the-docs theme.)

---

I found that some CSS can transform `<kbd>`-tags into nice looking keys.

```
kbd
{
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  background-color:#f7f7f7;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:3px;
  box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 2px #fff inset;
  color:#333;
  display:inline-block;
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:1.4;
  margin:0 .1em;
  padding:.1em .6em;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

Source: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4788/css-for-the-new-kbd-style

Comment: Here is a related discussion on [sphinx-doc](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3160#issuecomment-340228635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [relevant issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3160) is now closed, and Sphinx does use `kbd` tags.